# Which image for steganography?

Tags: steganography

Which images are suitable for image **steganography**(Storing behind an image)?
In particular **JPEG,BMP** or **TIFF**?
As JPEG is lossy so is it possible to lose any data if it is hidden behind the image?(using LS**strong text** technique)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically any of these can be used, but you are more likely to see jpeg in use in the wild.  Because the steganography is a basically introducing imperfections in the image to hide a message, the imperfections will be less noticeable in an already lossy format, whereas if you had some off pixels in a bitmapped image, one is more likely to notice the discrepancy.

Your question about being lossy only applies if someone tries to resave the image.  For example if I opened your image with a secret message hidden in it in photoshop and then saved it back out as a jpeg, the image would likely change and destroy your message. This is not the case when sending a file via e-mail or the web (except in the case of some ISPs that implement jpeg compression to speed up browsing speeds for slower connections like dialup).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest image type for Steganography using LSB technique is a BMP image. It is not a popular image type as it occupies a larger size than its counter parts(jpg).